# How can I check service status using Ansible and compare that value with the expected value provided by client?

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I have a code to check service status however it is not working as expected. Any advice on it would be of great help, also I need to know how can various service statuses be verified and compared using this code.

Tasks file for ypbind_tab3

```yaml
    - shell: "systemctl status ypbind.service "
      register: _cat
    - assert:
        that:
          - lookup('file', 'customer-expects.txt') == _cat.stdout
        fail_msg: missed
        success_msg: matched
```

The output is

```sh
[root@ansible-master /]# ansible-playbook tab3.role.yml -v
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [This output is for Tab-3 of Function Design document] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-client]

TASK [ypbind_tab3 : shell] **************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ansible-client]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "systemctl status ypbind.service ", "delta": "0:00:00.013814", "end": "2022-01-08 15:30:27.082785", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 4, "start": "2022-01-08 15:30:27.068971", "stderr": "Unit ypbind.service could not be found.", "stderr_lines": ["Unit ypbind.service could not be found."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
ansible-client             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: The error is `Unit ypbind.service could not be found`. Please check if the service is actually available on the target machine. As @Vladimir Botka suggested in his answer, you can use service facts instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *shell* use the module [*service_facts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html#ansible-builtin-service-facts-return-service-state-information-as-fact-data). For example

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.service_facts:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services['sshd.service']
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.debug] **************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  ansible_facts.services['sshd.service']:
    name: sshd.service
    source: systemd
    state: active
    status: enabled
```

Then you can test the state of the service. For example, given the file

```sh
shell> cat customer-expects-sshd-state.txt
active
```

the task below

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.assert:
        that:
          - lookup('file', 'customer-expects-sshd-state.txt') ==
            ansible_facts.services['sshd.service']['state']
        fail_msg: missed
        success_msg: matched
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [ansible.builtin.assert] ************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: matched
```

Comment: Apologies as I was not clear with my comments. I have deleted them, sorry for not been clear with it.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance it helped resolve my issue.